# how to nullify register in system verilog

Tags: verilog, verification, system-verilog

How do I nullify a register in SystemVerilog if I do not know the size? 
For example, if I have:

```
reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] data_stack;
```

with some parameter `DATA_WIDTH` given to the module. Is it possible to assign a zero to the register `data_stack`?

Note that it is sufficient to initialize a similar `reg` to zero as then I can simply perform a bitwise and between the two and nullify `data_stack`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to know how to generate a zero value with the same width as `data_stack`?

In that case, use the replication operator:

```
data_stack = {DATA_WIDTH{1'b0}};
```

This generates `DATA_WIDTH` number of zeros.

Answer (score 6):

The IEEE Std 1800-2009 is the golden reference.  The following sets all bits to 0:

```
data_stack = '0;
```

Refer to the section "Integer literal constants".

> An unsized single-bit value can be specified by preceding the
>   single-bit value with an apostrophe ( ' ), but without the base
>   specifier. All bits of the unsized value shall be set to the value of
>   the specified bit. In a self-determined context, an unsized single-bit
>   value shall have a width of 1 bit, and the value shall be treated as
>   unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

I think your searches would yield better results if you searched for initialising registers, instead of nullify.

If this is a testbench variable then just :

```
initial begin
  data_stack = {DATA_WIDTH{1'b0}};
end
```

If it is to be used in a flip-flop you need to reset it:

```
always @(posedge clk or negedge reset_n) begin
  if (~reset_n) begin
    data_stack <= {DATA_WIDTH{1'b0}};
  end
  else begin
    //<=nextvalue;
  end
end
```